# MPI number of threads

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mpi

How can I set the number of MPI threads in Microsoft Visual studio 2010?
(I usually work in linux and in the command line I can do "mpiexec -np 10 ./program")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same for most MPI implementations (though they are processes, not threads). You can usually use -np, but you can also use -n in MPICH derivatives (of which MS-MPI is one).